# Get list element from a panda list column based of value of different column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame with a list column as follows.

```
    selection  weeks
0   2            [43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52]
1   3            [43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52]
2   1            [43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52]
```

How would I be able to get first N elements based on `selection` value to get the following result?

```
    selection  weeks                                     select_week 
0   2          [43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52]  [43, 44]
1   3          [43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52]  [43, 44, 45]
2   1          [43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52]  [43]
```

Comment: Will the length of lists be the same throughout the column `weeks`?

Comment: @Ch3steR - yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use list comprehension with select by indexing:

```
df['select_week'] = [x[:y] for x, y in df[['weeks','selection']].to_numpy()]
```

Or [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df['select_week'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['weeks'][:x['selection']], axis=1)
```

Comment: Hi. I had a stupid doubt. Why will this not work? `df.weeks.str[0: df.selection]` ?

Comment: @MayankPorwal - Because `.str[:N]` working only with scalars, so cannot pass another column